# PyQt keyReleaseEvent, how to ignore key repeat from OS when the key is held down?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, action, user-input

I'm facing the current problem with the way I'm handling events in PyQt5. I want my GUI to start an action when the user presses a key, and stop when the user releases the key.

But currently, because of the key repeat feature in most operating systems, the action that I want starts and stops rapidly. Disabling this feature isn't an option for me since I can't control what keyboard settings the user of my software has.

For example in the code below, if I held down the 'C' key for 5 seconds I want this to be the output:

```
Started Cool action!
Stopped Cool action!
```

But instead, I get this:

```
Started Cool action!
Stopped Cool action!
Started Cool action!
Stopped Cool action!
Started Cool action!
Stopped Cool action!
Started Cool action!
...
```

The code in question:

```
def keyReleaseEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_C:
        #stop doing cool action
        print ('Stopped Cool action!')
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == Qt.Key_C:
        #Start doing Cool Action
        print ('Started Cool action!')
```

Is there anyway I can bypass the repeated keyboard inputs, is there a workaround here? Thanks!

Comment: [QKeyEvent.isAutoRepeat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#isAutoRepeat).